# CheckMarx XSRF attack issue

Tags: java, csrf, static-code-analysis, checkmarx, secure-coding

I have a REST controller, which has a method `deleteStudent` which accepts two parameters 
`studentId` which is `Long` and `section` which is `String`.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/deleteStudent/studentId/{studentId}/section/{section}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public  Student deleteStudent(@PathVariable Long studentId, @PathVariable String section){
    return studentService.deleteStudent(studentId ,section);
}
```

For above code checkmarx is complaining *This parameter value flows through the code and is eventually used to modify database contents. 
The application does not require renewed user authentication for the request. This may enable Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF).*

I have tried   `Htmlutils.htmlescape` ( from spring web util) on section but no luck.

How to get rid of this checkmarx issue?

One more thing how  XSRF   and SQL injection attack is possible  if field is  of Long type ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's talking about the `studentId` parameter and not the `section` parameter?

If it is indeed, I'd say it's a false-positive.

If it's talking about the `section` parameter, I wouldn't worry at all if your SQL requests are secured (so if you use an ORM or prepared statements, etc...).

Overall, I'd say it's a false-positive in all the cases for SQL injections.

That said, for [CSRF attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery), you might indeed be vulnerable.

If a hacker makes an administrator load the page it will be able to delete any user account even without having the accesses if you don't implement CSRF protection.

Comment: I have implemented filter  which add unique csrf token but still it is complaining about csrf attack

Comment: If you are sure that the CSRF protection is working properly, then it might be a false positive. I don't know the tool you're using, but maybe it's not able to detect that there is a protection, especially if it's only analyzing the code and not testing it functionally...

Comment: @saurabh what filter is that? Your code snippet does not contain any anti csrf token...

Comment: @yaloner It's spring code, if there is anti-CSRF protection code it's definitely not located in the controllers but rather in a configuration class.

Comment: @AntoineB Exactly. We cannot answer a CSRF question without you supplying all the necessary info including your anti-CSRF implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Comment from Spring Security(https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html):

> When you use CSRF protection? Our recommendation is to use CSRF
> protection for any request that could be processed by a browser by
> normal users. If you are only creating a service that is used by
> non-browser clients, you will likely want to disable CSRF protection.

If your service is only consumed by non-browser clients, you can exclude the XSRF query from your preset.

If not, here is how Checkmarx checking if you have verify cross site request forgery token (Java/Cx/General/Find_XSRF_Sanitize):

1. **method invocation**: `getNewXsrfToken`, `setRpcToken`, `verifyCSRFToken`, `isTokenValid`
2. **variable names**: "*token*", "*csrf*", "*xsrf*", "nonce", "*captcha*"

These **methods invocation** and **variable names** are used in a method decalaration. From inside these method body of these method decalarations, all these requests are considered sanitized, and are removed from the potential tainted request list.

All these source code element found by CxQL query `Find_Interactive_Inputs` are requests.